# How to check if two last characters in string correspond to array 1 + array 2

Tags: php, arrays, substr

I really don't know how to find this.

Basically, I want my script to check a word, for example:

'word'

I also have two arrays:

```
$vowels=array("a","o","i","u","á","ó","í","ú","é","ō","ē");    $consonants=array("b","c","d","f","g","h","j","k","l","m","n","p","q","r","s","t","v","w","x","z");
```

The code should check if the last two characters of the string contain a combination of vowel + consonant.

Not consonant + consonant or consonant + vowel. But it seems harder than it looks to do it. To check the last two characters I use:

```
$lastletters= substr($word['Word'], -2);
```

The problem is that I don't know how to check the word with an array in the substr.

```
if($lastletters="$vowels"."$consonants")
```

doesn't work, and

```
if($lastletters=$vowels.$consonants)
```

simply doesn't work.

Comment: use `==` instead of `=`

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: `"$foo"` and `$foo` are functionaly identical in PHP. using `"$foo"` is just cargo-cult programming.

Comment: I already use ==, doesn't work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression for that.

```
$vowelsStr = implode('', $vowels);
$conStr = implode('', $consonants);
if (preg_match('/['.$vowelsStr.']['.$conStr.']$/', $word)) {
  // found it
}
```

Comment: I don't get why you are downvoted, your answer was the only one working, at first the answer of Mr. Llama worked, but it didn't work anymore for words with é and á. PHP seems to have a lot of problems, as you always encounter problems related to Unicode. All my current problems are related to Unicode. :S

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
if (in_array(substr($word, -2, 1), $vowels) && in_array(substr($word, -1, 1), $consonants)) {
   // $word ends with vowel the consonant.
}
```

The trick is using [`in_array`](https://www.php.net/in_array) to check if the given character is in the character array.
Please note that the comparison is *case sensitive*.  If you need the comparison to be *case insensitive*, convert `$word` to lowercase before comparing.

Comment: It works! Thanks man, could you explain how it exactly works? The only part in your code which I don't understand completely is in_array, does in_array mean that a string is checked with an array?

Comment: Check the documentation link in the answer.  `in_array` takes two inputs: `$needle` and `$heystack` where `$heystack` is an array.  It returns true if `$needle` is an element in `$heystack`.

Comment: There seems to be a problem. I have a word with the last 2 characters:   úr.

Comment: When I put "ú" in the array $vowels  and use your code, it doesn't work. :S

Comment: @user3749746 - It seems that `in_array` has issues with unicode characters.  You may have to convert them to unaccented forms using `iconv` and use that with `in_array`.